# Google Cloud Console access for invited users

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-identity

I registered a domain (for ex. mydomain.com) and I opened a Cloud Identity (free edition) account attached to that domain.

Then I configured a Google Cloud access for this Admin user.
So, I finally had my Cloud Identity account with my user as an admin, my organization and my Google Cloud account with which I can access Google Cloud Console.

After accessing Google Cloud Console, I setted up the payment and billing profile for my organization;
I created also some groups and additional users through Google Admin console. All of them belong to mydomain.com; so for example I created an additional user adam@mydomain.com that belong to gcp-network-admins and gcp-security-admins groups.

adam@mydomain.com received an invitation email. If he tries to login to Google Cloud Console he gets a 3 step wizard where on the last step the system ask him to enter billing and payment info to access and start using Google Cloud. I don't understand why and I'm not sure if I did something wrong.

kind regards,
Matt

Comment: Based on my experience, Upon my first login I tried to link my GCP console to Organization Billing account. Worth to check also if the user was created is also a biling user or owner. Can you share the Role Permissions of the adam user under IAM page?

Comment: hello @JaysonM, I assigned the role "billing user" to the user and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Posting as an answer.

Based on my experience, Upon my first login I tried to link my GCP console to Organization Billing account. Worth to check also if the user was created is also a biling user or owner.

Comment: Hi @JaysonM, I setted the created user as a billing user, and he was able to login without having to create a new billing account. Thank you.